# EJB3.1 client max connection for each EJB facade

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, wildfly

For example we have 2 EJB stateless facades UserFacade and ContactFacade.
Client is tomcat web application which sometimes do remote calls to UserFacade and to ContactFacade.
In JBoss we have configuration like

```
<!-- Maximum number of connections in client invoker's    -->
   <!-- connection pool (socket transport).  Defaults to 50. -->
   <!--entry><key>clientMaxPoolSize</key> <value>20</value></entry-->
```

[Link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Remote_EJB_Clients.html)

Is this configuration for every EJB3 facade? For example if clientMaxPoolSize is 50, it means what it is 50 for  UserFacade and 50 for ContactFacade? Or it means what it is 25 for each facade?

And is it useful in client side/application keep connection pool and do remote call via connection pool and if for each facade connection count increased over than 25(50) clear connections or do another actions.

In some client applications I used connection pool, it has some advantages and disadvantages. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this configuration for every EJB3 facade? For example if clientMaxPoolSize is 50, it means what it is 50 for UserFacade and 50 for ContactFacade? Or it means what it is 25 for each facade?

Ans : It will Allow 50 for UserFacade and 50 for ContacrFacade

And is it useful in client side/application keep connection pool and do remote call via connection pool and if for each facade connection count increased over than 25(50) clear connections or do another actions.

Ans : It will go in wait mode and wait for the connections to be available.

In some client applications I used connection pool, it has some advantages and disadvantages. Any suggestions?

Ans : Connection pool is good for those who wants to serve large number of processing with lesser hardware. But make sure your configuration are according to your average application load